# Complex SOQL query for parent/child records

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex, soql

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to build a query.  I have a "Category" object and in that category object there is a "Parent_Category__c" field.  The category is for a Product (and there is a "Product_Category__c" junction object that links categories to products.) A product can have multiple levels of parent categories.

```
Product -> Product_Category__c -> Category <--|
                                      |_______|
```

The way the system (which I inherited) is built is causing me to start from bottom-up.  So I have to find the product first, then find the product_category__c, and then find the all the categories__c.  So I get the lowest level child category. What is an efficient way to query all the way up to the root category -- keeping in mind I will have to do this a few thousand times for each product.

I had thought about querying all categories and storing them in a map for reference but I don't know how many categories this client will have.  It could get large.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to go with recursive route...